# Delete all temp files

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command

```
DEL %TEMP%/*. /F /Q /S & ECHO Success > LOG.TXT & TYPE LOG.TXT & DEL LOG.TXT
```

Hello stack overflow! I am writing a simple script in Windows to clean up my temp files. Because I am weird and do not like paragraphs of script, I need to use one liners like above. The above is supposed to clear my temp folder. When I run this, I get an error.Anybody willing to help error-spot? thanks all!

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't bother to tell us what error you see, we're forced to make assumptions.

The glaringly obvious problem is

```
DEL %TEMP%/*.
```

should be

```
DEL "%TEMP%\*."
```

since <kbd>\</kbd> is a directory-separator and <kbd>/</kbd> is a switch in winbatch. Some commands accept <kbd>/</kbd> as directory separators, but not all.

`%temp%` typically contains separators, so it needs to be quoted else `del` will attempt to delete each separated element, probably generating an error message.

Your generation, listing and deleting a file seems pointless.

Comment: Thank you. Apologies for not writing the error. Silly mistake. I want to see the contents of the file, but I didn't want to keep it. And your assumption was right it definitely worked. Thank you @Magoo!